# BigInt type isn't maintained in conversion to hex from decimal

Tags: javascript, types, hex, bigint

I have some data that contains large numbers that I read in and store as strings. I need to convert them to hexadecimal strings, but when I try to use the BigInt(decimalString).toString(16) the bigInt type is not maintained as the last character of the hex value is still cut off.

```js
const decimal = '18446744072635809797'
console.log(decimal)
// Expected: 18446744072635809797 Actual: 18446744072635810000 FAIL

console.log(BigInt(decimal))
// Expected: 18446744072635809792n Actual: 18446744072635809792n SUCCESS

console.log(BigInt(decimal).toString(16))
// Expected: ffffffffc0000005 Actual: "ffffffffc0000000 FAIL
```

The strangest part is trying this same code in JSFiddle works exactly as expected, but in my environment it does not. Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "ES5",
     "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "ESNext.BigInt"],
     "allowJs": true,
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
     "strict": true,
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
     "module": "esnext",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "resolveJsonModule": true,
     "isolatedModules": true,
     "noEmit": true,
     "jsx": "react-jsx"
    },
"include": ["src"]
}
```

I see the same behavior happen between browsers (Edge and Chrome) as well. What am I missing?

The json file is basically something like this
{
a: 18446744072635809797
}
That I save to a javascript object using an interface to convert it to a string:

```js
interface IData{
  a: string
}

service.GetData().then((data: IData) => {
  if(data.a > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER){
    const decimal = BigInt(data.a)
    // attempt to convert decimal to hex
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand your first `FAIL`. You're just logging a string, it shouldn't change.

Comment: Did you mean to write `decimal.toString()`?

Comment: In Edge on Windows 10 x64 I get proper results, in fact just tried `1844674407263580979734234243423423424234323423423423423423423498992837497209387092387098723423423423459439803409850978345978` number and it returned `2ca5dfb8b507cc0c94b5770e8150988502caabf4a4060b810e6bc5abd7a42083b9dfb15d0bf197c8f9d0eb5891f5d110cf923fa`

Comment: So what's your environment than?

Comment: @Barmar values are different in the first FAIL. I was expecting the value to log as it is in the string, but it logs it as if it was converted to a number first so it's less precise. Adding "tostring()" does not change this behavior

Comment: I'm in a create-react-app project on Windows 10 x64

Comment: After digging into this further I'm realizing that the data coming from the server needs to be a string in order to maintain the precision,  and cannot be converted on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The json file is basically something like this `{ a: 18446744072635809797 }`

That's your problem: the value is a number, and is parsed as a number. The JSON should be `{ a: "18446744072635809797" }`, then you'd get the behavior you expect by passing this string to the `BigInt` function, e.g. `BigInt(data.a).toString(16)`.

A TypeScript interface definition doesn't cause any conversions to be performed. Even if it did, by the time `JSON.parse` returns it's already too late, as the bits that couldn't be stored in a `Number` have already been lost at that point.

See for yourself:

```
> JSON.parse('{ "a": 18446744072635809797 }')
← {a: 18446744072635810000}
> JSON.parse('{ "a": "18446744072635809797" }')
← {a: '18446744072635809797'}
```